# Clustered Column Chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a clustered column chart in Excel and am pretty close to what I need. However, I got stuck and in need of some help.

Here is my data:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8s5h2ynrzx5tll/data.pdf?dl=0]

This is the figure I have at the moment:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0a3e2spgfsg6j50/graph.pdf?dl=0]

What I need is:

1. blue and green columns should stick together followed by some gap.
2. blue and pink columns should stick together followed by some gap.
3. orange column should stand alone.

Could you please suggest a way forward?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

1. Add empty rows where you want a gap in your chart, something like this:

[image]

2. Insert the chart, you should have something like this:

[image]

3. Select and right-click on one of the bars, then choose "Format Data Series" from the popup menu

[image]

4. Type 0% for both "Series Overlap" and "Gap Width"

[image]

You chart should now look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Meanwhile, I also ended up finding a solution similar to yours.